# vue-form doesn't work with vue-material

Tags: javascript, vue-material

When I use vue form on normal html `<input>` tag, validate is working.
When I use `<md-input>` instead  validate doesn't work and I get the following error:

> Element with v-model not found

Working example with `<input>`

```
<vue-form :state="formState" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">

  <validate>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input v-model="model.name" required name="name" />

    <field-messages name="name">
      <div>Success!</div>
      <div slot="required">Name is a required field</div>
    </field-messages>
  </validate>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</vue-form>
```

Not working example with `<md-input>`

```
<vue-form :state="formState" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">

  <validate>
    <md-input-container md-inline>
      <label>Name</label>
      <md-input v-model="model.name" required name="name"></md-input>
    </md-input-container>

    <field-messages name="name">
      <div>Success!</div>
      <div slot="required">Name is a required field</div>
    </field-messages>
  </validate>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</vue-form>
```

Comment: If you are using the [vuematerial](https://vuematerial.io/) consider migrate to [quasar](http://quasar-framework.org/). I had a bad experience using vue material.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use md-field and md-input tags.